# Delay angular-ui modal from closing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using `angularjs` with the `angular-ui` library (specially the `angular-ui-bootstrap` one).

How can I delay a modal from closing? After the user clicks on the `x`, or Cancel button, I need the modal to stay visible for an extra half second, but I haven't found a way to do it.

I was thinking to add some timeout in the callback function that is passed into the `then` function of the modal instance, such as:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function success(){
    // timeout .5 second
}, function cancel() {
   // timeout .5 second
});
```

but the code in the callback functions is actually run after the modal has been close. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What code are you using to close the modal? Also, why do you want to modal to stick around for longer?

Comment: I am not using any code to close the modal, just the default built-in. The reason is a hack to avoid some flashing effect (if I open one modal, close it and there is another one poping up).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
 $timeout(function() {
     $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
 }, 500);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8QQvmrKtsticVsdaNgdh?p=preview)

Complete code with seperate controller of modal :-

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance,$timeout, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $timeout(function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }, 500);

  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the plunker, I didn't know I could override the cancel function. Do you mind editing your answer so it includes the whole controller? For future reference. Thanks